# How can I add my app icon to the recent tabs?

Tags: android, icons

I am trying to build my app in android studio 3.0, I have noticed they changed the image asset window and how it works. My problem is when I am adding a new icon, It does not add it to the tab (not tabs like tabbed activity, the recent apps tab),
is there a way to fix it?

I will send a demonstration:
[regular icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9U7N.jpg)

[tab icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nZvi.jpg)

[Res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL99Z.png)

I am using a xiaomi redmi note 4 qualcomm

Comment: Can you post screenshot of drawable or mipmap folder and XML of screen?

Comment: Thanks for answering, it's kinda midnight, I'll send it tomorrow

Comment: added a screenshot of my mipmap